# consequence of $E|X| < \infty$ on conditional expectation of $X$ on sets $A$ of small size.

Tags: probability-theory

Question 5.6.5 of Probability and random processes by Grimmett,

Show that $E|X| < \infty$ if and only if the following holds: for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $E(X|I_A)<\epsilon$ for all $A$ such that $P(A) < \delta$.

So $E|X|< \infty$ means that the $X$ is integrable on its domain. We want to show that for all subset $A$ of the domain of $X$ whose measure is less than $\delta$, then integral of $X$ on $A$ is less than $\epsilon$.

Suppose not, then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that  for all $\delta>0$ there is a set $A$ with $P(A)< \delta$ and $E(X|I_A)\geq \epsilon$.

Then I don't know what to do anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to double-check the notation. $E(X|I_{A})$ is not condition
expectation, it should be the usual expectation $E(XI_{A})=\int XI_{A}\,dP$.
The results can be proved immediately by dominated convergence theorem.
Note that the results continue to hold even if the measure under consideration
is not a finite measure.

Proof: In the following proof, we do not need the fact that $P(\Omega)<\infty$.
That is, the same argument works for a general measure space. For
each $n$, let $A_{n}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid|X(\omega)|\leq n\}$.
Define $X_{n}=XI_{A_{n}}$. Obviously, $X_{n}\rightarrow X$ pointwisely.
Moreover, $|X_{n}|\leq|X|$. By Dominated Convergence Theorem, we
have: $\int|X_{n}-X|\,dP\rightarrow0$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Fix an $n$ such that $\int|X_{n}-X|dP<\varepsilon/2$.
Define $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{2n}>0$. For any $B\in\mathcal{F}$
with $P(B)<\delta$, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{B}|X|dP & \leq & \int_{B}|X-X_{n}|dP+\int_{B}|X_{n}|dP\\
 & \leq & \int|X-X_{n}|dP+nP(B)\\
 & < & \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+n\delta\\
 & = & \varepsilon
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: sorry can you explain $\int |X_n-X|dP \to 0$? dominated convergence theorem states that if a sequence of measurable functions $f_n$ converges to a function $f$ and that each $|f_n|$ is bounded by a integrable function $g$ then we can change the limit and integration of the sequence. So here each $X_n$ is bounded by $X$ . so we know integral of $\int X= lim_{n\to \infty} \int(X_n)$

Comment: $|X_{n}-X|\leq2|X|$ and $2|X|$ is an integrable function. Note that
$|X_{n}-X|\rightarrow0$ pointwisely, so by Dominated Convergence
Theorem we have $\int|X_{n}-X|\rightarrow\int0=0$.

Comment: How do we prove the reverse direction?

Answer (score 0):

For the reverse direction to hold, your random variable $X$ must
be real-valued. Otherwise, counter-example can be constructed easily.
For example, if $X$ is allowed to take $\infty$, we may consider
probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, where $\Omega=\{\omega_{0}\}$,
$\mathcal{F}=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$, and $P(\emptyset)=0$, $P(\Omega)=1$.
Define $X(\omega_{0})=\infty$. Then $X:\Omega\rightarrow[-\infty,\infty]$
is measurable. Given $\varepsilon>0$, we choose $\delta=\frac{1}{2}$.
For any $A\in\mathcal{F}$ with $P(A)<\delta$, $A$ must be $A=\emptyset$.
Therefore $\int_{A}|X|dP=0<\varepsilon$. However, $\int|X|dP=\infty$.

If $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is real-valued, the converse does
hold.

Proof: Let $A_{n}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid|X(\omega)|>n\}$. Clearly,
$A_{1}\supseteq A_{2}\supseteq\ldots$ and $\cap A_{n}=\emptyset$
(Note that if $X$ can take value $\infty$ or $-\infty$, we no longer
have $\cap_{n}A_{n}=\emptyset$). By continuity of measure, we have
$\lim_{n}P(A_{n})=P(\cap_{n}A_{n})=P(\emptyset)=0$. Now, let $\varepsilon=1$,
then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\int_{A}|X|<\varepsilon$
whenever $P(A)<\delta$. Choose $n$ such that $P(A_{n})<\delta$,
then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int|X| & = & \int_{A_{n}^{c}}|X|+\int_{A_{n}}|X|\\
 & \leq & nP(A_{n}^{c})+\varepsilon\\
 & \leq & n+1\\
 & < & \infty.
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that $X$ is integrable.